# Downloading ms_graph module

Tags: python, terminal, microsoft-graph-api

I have been trying to download ms_graph module, but none of the available terminal command has been useful. I tried the following command.

> pip install Install-Module Microsoft.Graph -Scope CurrentUser
> brew install ms_graph

I am currently trying to download in mac.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The installation of the Microsoft Graph Python SDK (preview): please use the following Code:

```
python -m pip install msgraph-core
python -m pip install azure-identity
```

Note:
[image]

The installation steps are also mentioned in [Microsoft Graph Core Python Client Library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python-core#microsoft-graph-core-python-client-library-preview) , Please check for reference.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to download the module in omega server and it still shows “No matching distribution found”